# why do my illustrator made svg files not come out as single lines

Tags: import

I am interested in importing illustrator paths into my blender fill as curves to use for extruding other circle curves (to make shaped tubes, essentially). But when I import them they aren't curves, they appear as filled. I don't want all the triangles there, just the curves themselves. Can someone help me figure this out? Thank you.

Note - all of the curves selected in illustrators are separate curves, no stroke, no fill. I want to import them as all separate curves.

[image]

[image]

added illustrator pic
[image]

link to file https://www.dropbox.com/s/rz6wsd5w1xvy3hd/paths2%20copy.ai?dl=0

Comment: Can you share a small Illustrator file that demonstrates the problem? I'm assuming these are SVG files?

Comment: thank you for answering! i uploaded the illustrator file to dropbox and posted a screenshot

Comment: Try going in the object data properties tab, change the shape to 2D (if it's not already) and the fill mode to none. You would have to do that in each curve object.

Comment: hmmm... weirdly turning it from 2d to 3d turned it into the curve without the fill! thank you for alerting me to this tool (I am like a week into learning blender) and have a good day. it's amazing how helpful people are on here. :)